# Module names in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to figure out the strange logic behind the modules naming in Android Studio.

See this screenshot from my project:

[image]

There is a lot of anomalies here:

- Some modules are just bold and contain NO square brackets
- Some modules are regular and do have the bold "other" name in square brackets
- Some directories containing modules are bold even though these are NOT modules (just folders)
- Some directories containing modules are regular and do have the bold "other" name in square brackets

The corresponding settings.gradle is like this:

```
rootProject.name='MbiSdkSampleApp'
include ':shared'
include ':backend:none'
include ':backend:mock'
include ':backend:nimbus'
include ':config:assets'
include ':config:mock'
include ':config:backend'
include ':resources:assets'
include ':resources:mock'
include ':resources:backend'
include ':user:backend'
include ':user:demo'
include ':fp:assets'
include ':fp:mock'
include ':fp:real'
include ':face:assets'
include ':app'
```

The names of physical directories are **EXACTLY** the same as the names of the includes above.

It is not any big issue as everything works normally (except of the ugly display), I just would like to understand what happens here...

Any ideas?

BTW: I am on the latest stable Android Studio, currently 4.0.

And yes, I went through the usual "fixing" of Android Studio issues by exercising hacks like "Invalidate Caches and Restart", etc.

Also: The other views (Project Files, Android) seem to be OK... I tend to conclude that this may be an Android Studio bug (one of sooo many I am experiencing all the time - UGHHH)...

Comment: rootProject.name='MbiSdkSampleApp' remove this may be solve it

Answer (score 1):

Android studio displays full module name in square brackets because there are multiple modules with the same name in your project (from your example: `backend:mock`, `config:backend`, etc..). Note that `backend` is considered a module in gradle even though there is no explicit `:backend` in your settings.gradle. Same applies for submodules `*:mock`, `*:assets`.

Bolding only module name is probably done to make it easier to differentiate between directory name and module name.